# Fermat's Little Theorem: Proving an integer exists which satisfies the following criteria mod $5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

This question has been tantalizing me for a day now:

> Given integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $d \neq 0$ (mod $5$) and $m$ an integer for which $am^3 + bm^2 +cm+d \equiv 0$ (mod $5$), prove there exists an integer $n$ for which $dn^3+cn^2+bn+a \equiv 0 $ (mod $5$).

My attempt:

---

It is easy to see that $\gcd(5,m)=1$. We know from Fermat's little theorem that $5 \mid m^4 -1 \Rightarrow 5 \mid (m+1)(m-1)(m^2+1)$. The proof is trivial that $5$ only divides one of these factors. Hence we have $3$ cases:

Case $1 \rightarrow m \equiv 1$ (mod $5$). If this is true then  it follows that $m^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $5$) and $m^3 \equiv 1$ (mod $5$). We can substitute $m$ into the equation and achieve:

$$a+b+c+d \equiv 0 \pmod5$$
$$\Rightarrow d(1)^3+c(1)^2+b(1)+a \equiv 0 \pmod5$$

Where $1$ satisfies the condition.

Case $2 \rightarrow m \equiv -1$ (mod $5$). If this is true then  it follows that $m^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $5$) and $m^3 \equiv -1$ (mod $5$). We can substitute $m$ into the equation and achieve:

$$a-b+c-d \equiv 0 \pmod5$$
$$\Rightarrow d(-1)^3+c(-1)^2+b(-1)+a \equiv 0 \pmod5$$

Where $-1$ satisfies the condition.

Case $3 \rightarrow m^2 \equiv -1$ (mod $5$). If this is true then  it follows that $m \equiv 2$ (mod $5$) and $m^3 \equiv -2$ (mod $5$). We can substitute $m$ into the equation and achieve:

$$2a+b-2c-d \equiv 0 \pmod5$$

From where I am unable to proceed. Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m\not\equiv0\bmod5$, since otherwise $d\equiv0\bmod5$, contradicting the given facts. Hence, since $5$ is a prime number, $m$ has an inverse modulo $5$ – let $n$ be this inverse. Multiplying $am^3+bm^2+cm+d\equiv0\bmod5$ by $n^3$, we can easily verify that $n$ satisfies the final congruence.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by inverse modulo $5$? I did not know such a thing existed — I am using Burton's book.

Comment: @NamanKumar $mn\equiv1\bmod5$.

Comment: Please strive to organize FAQs - not post more dupe answers to them.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry, I do not believe this is a FAQ.

Comment: But it is, and it is also an easy dupe to locate.

Comment: @BillDubuque The duplicate you have linked is a more general result, yes, and I can understand it, but the OP may not. And in some cases the OP asks a new question because of the non-understanding.